# Firebase retrieving data into listview, but showing empty tabs

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have difficulty retrieving data from firebase using my custom adapter. My listview shows empty tabs. [Empty listview tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lJxa.jpg)

My firebase contains data [Firebase information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzIUC.png)

How my app works is that in the first activity page, it uploads informations while the second activity page retrieves that information. The uploading portion has no problem but the downloading of the information and putting it in listview presents the empty tabs problem.

My custom adapter:

```
private Activity context;
private List<patientinfo> patientinfoList;

public PatientlistAdapter(Activity context, List<patientinfo> patientinfoList){
    super(context, R.layout.patientlist_detail, patientinfoList);
    this.context = context;
    this.patientinfoList = patientinfoList;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return patientinfoList.size();
}

@Override
public patientinfo getItem(int position) {
    return patientinfoList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patientlist_detail,null,true);

    TextView qnTV = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.qnTV);
    TextView appointmenttimeTV = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.appointmenttimeTV);
    TextView descriptionTV = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTV);

    patientinfo patientinfo1 = patientinfoList.get(position);

    qnTV.setText(patientinfo1.getqueuenumber());
    appointmenttimeTV.setText(patientinfo1.getappointmenttime());
    descriptionTV.setText(patientinfo1.getpatientinitials());

    return listViewItem;
}
```

My List:

```
public class patientinfo {


String queuenumber,appointmenttime,patientinitials;

public String getqueuenumber() { return queuenumber; }

public String getappointmenttime() {
    return appointmenttime;
}

public String getpatientinitials() {
    return patientinitials;
}
}
```

Sorry if the subjects are confusing as I am an amateur with little to no background experience/knowledge on this. I learned this from following youtube videos. Please help me out anyone?

Comment: classes in java always in camelcase patientinfo will be PatientInfo, and make your queuenumber,appointmenttime,patientinitials private

Comment: Thank you, I will take note of this from now on

Comment: check in xml whats the text color?

Comment: try using recycler view listview is deprecated now.

Comment: Okay, I will give recycler view a try if I still can't figure this problem out. Thanks!

Comment: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html will help you to style your code even better

Answer (score 0):

in your `onStart()` remove the `clear()` that is inside `onDataChange` and add above the listener:

```
 patientinfoList.clear();
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot patientsnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        patientinfo patientinfo = patientsnapshot.getValue(patientinfo.class);
        patientinfoList.add(patientinfo);

}
```

Add the `clear()` above to prevent duplicate data when `onStart()` gets executed. Also adding `clear()` inside onDataChange will result in empty listview

Edit:

```
 public class Patientinfo {
private String queuenumber,appointmenttime,patientinitials,arrivaltime;
public Patientinfo{
  }

   public Patientinfo(String queunumber,String appointmenttime,String patientinitials,String arrivaltime) {
    this.queunumber=queunumber;
    this.appointmenttime=appointmenttime;
    this.patientinitials=patientinitials;
    this.arrivaltime=arrivaltime;
}

public String getQueuenumber() { 
 return queuenumber; 
 }
  public String getArrivaltime() { 
 return arrivaltime; 
 }
 public void setArrivaltime() { 
this.arrivaltime=arrivaltime; 
 }

public String getAppointmenttime() {
return appointmenttime;
}

public String getPatientinitials() {
return patientinitials;
}

  public void setPatientinitials(String patientinitials) {
    this.patientinitials=patientinitials;
}
 public void setAppointmenttime(String appointmenttime) {
    this.appointmenttime=appointmenttime;
}
  public void setQueuenumber(String queuenumber) {
    this.queuenumber=queuenumber;
}
}
```

Comment: try this @Guesthouse

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
PatientlistAdapter adapter = new PatientlistAdapter(pharmacy01main.this, patientinfoList);
patientlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In a word, you can try to add `notifyDataSetChanged();`

And I'm feeling that your code is very strange. If you are getting same problem, could you show me firebase database structure?

Comment: Did you check whether patientinfoList has any elements or not?

Comment: How do I check whether it has any elements in it?

Comment: hmm.. First, you can set break point.  And then you can use the log feature. please note https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Oh it says this on the Logcat:

No setter/field for Appointment Time found on class patientinfo
No setter/field for Queue Number found on class patientinfo
No setter/field for Patient's Initials found on class patientinfo
No setter/field for Arrival Time found on class patientinfo

Then how do I go about this??

Comment: you can make 
String queuenumber,appointmenttime,patientinitials;  as public members. And as I told you,  please check firebase node which has the same names exist or not.

Comment: There are some mistakes.  public void setArrivaltime() { 
this.arrivaltime=arrivaltime; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines after this-:

```
     PatientlistAdapter adapter = new PatientlistAdapter(pharmacy01main.this, patientinfoList);
            patientlistview.setAdapter(adapter);

if(adapter!=null)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It is still empty

Comment: wat's your text color in xml file and check if list contains anything or not?

Comment: Its black in color

Comment: try and print your list as Log.e("list is",""+patientinfoList);

Comment: The logcat says no setter/field is found on my patientinfo java file

Comment: your list is null. try checking the case where you are setting list to adapter

Comment: Can I know which part you are talking about? Sorry, I am really a noob at this

Comment: Here check patientinfo patientinfo = patientsnapshot.getValue(patientinfo.class);
            patientinfoList.add(patientinfo);

Log.e("size is",""+ patientinfoList.size());

if its 0 you are doing something wrong

Comment: I have include  Log.e("size is",""+ patientinfoList.size()); and it says E/size is 3. 

I have also include Log.e("list is",""+patientinfoList); and it says E/list is patientinfo@6684ea2, patientinfo@5ab0733, patientinfo@a75caf0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my listview was showing a list of empty cardviews, the mistake was silly. If anyone faces the same issue then make sure that the attribute names of the class(eg. here Patientinfo) and the name of the node from where you are retrieving its value should be the same.
For example here the name of the child nodes 'Appointment Time' in Firebase should be changed to 'appointmenttime' while pushing the value to the database as because it is spelled that way in the Patientinfo class.
Hope it helps.